# indexing through an array in blocks

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, multidimensional-array, neural-network

I have an image represented as an array (img), and I'd like to make many copies of the image, and in each copy zero out different squares of the image (in the first copy zero out 0:2,0:2 in the next copy zero out 0:2, 3:5 etc). I've used np.broadcast_to to create multiple copies of the image, but I'm having trouble indexing through the multiple copies of the image, and the multiple locations within the images to zero out squares within the image.

I think I'm looking for something like skimage.util.view_as_blocks, but I need to be able to write to the original array, not just read.

The idea behind this is to pass all the copies of the image through a neural network. The copy that performs the worst should be the one with the class (picture) I am trying to identify in its zero'd out location.

```
img = np.arange(10*10).reshape(10,10)
img_copies = np.broadcast_to(img, [100, 10, 10])
z = np.zeros(2*2).reshape(2,2)
```

Thanks

Comment: How are those `different squares` with `different locations` fed to the code? Would all of those squares be of the same shape?

Comment: Edited original post to be more specific. The different squares would start in the top left corner and in a non overlapping fashion cover the whole array. Each square would be the same size. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have cracked it! Here's an approach using `masking` along a `6D` reshaped array -

```
def block_masked_arrays(img, BSZ):
    # Store shape params
    m = img.shape[0]//BSZ
    n = m**2

    # Make copies of input array such that we replicate array along first axis.
    # Reshape such that the block sizes are exposed by going higher dimensional.
    img3D = np.tile(img,(n,1,1)).reshape(m,m,m,BSZ,m,BSZ)    

    # Create a square matrix with all ones except on diagonals. 
    # Reshape and broadcast it to match the "blocky" reshaped input array.
    mask = np.eye(n,dtype=bool).reshape(m,m,m,1,m,1)

    # Use the mask to mask out the appropriate blocks. Reshape back to 3D.
    img3D[np.broadcast_to(mask, img3D.shape)] = 0
    img3D.shape = (n,m*BSZ,-1)
    return img3D
```

Sample run -

```
In [339]: img
Out[339]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14, 15]])

In [340]: block_masked_arrays(img, BSZ=2)
Out[340]: 
array([[[ 0,  0,  2,  3],
        [ 0,  0,  6,  7],
        [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
        [12, 13, 14, 15]],

       [[ 0,  1,  0,  0],
        [ 4,  5,  0,  0],
        [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
        [12, 13, 14, 15]],

       [[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
        [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
        [ 0,  0, 10, 11],
        [ 0,  0, 14, 15]],

       [[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
        [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
        [ 8,  9,  0,  0],
        [12, 13,  0,  0]]])
```

Comment: That works, though I'm having trouble following your code, especially with the higher dimensionality. How does your function work? Thank you

Comment: @Aryeh Added few comments there.

Comment: Your function worked so I marked this as answered. Thank you. I'm still don't understand how you used the added dimensions, is there a name for the method you used, or some website you'd recommend so I can learn more about what you did? Thanks

Comment: @Aryeh I don't think there would be any external resource for it. As hinted at the start of the post, a lot of trial and error and intuition went into this. So, I do  understand your concern/feedback. I guess if you really want to dig deep and understand what's going on, you could start with a sample 1D `img` and then look to work with `1D` windows and play around with the reshaping. Once you are comfortable with `1D`, go to `2D`. Good luck!